# Is the logistic regression model integrable into the potential outcome framework?

Tags: regression, logistic, matching

(1) I preprocessed data with a matching method (CEM)

(2) On this data (binary dependent variable, explanatory variables) , I ran a logit model and estimate predicted probabilities or odds ratios.

I would like to integrate my estimates of the logit model into the potential outcome framework (I would like get an average treatment effect for the treated (ATT) of my explanatory variable)

I know it's possible for OLS (I found it in Gelman & Hill 2007, Chapter 9), but I did not find anything on logit.

Comment: This sounds the basis of propensity score matching, so I think the answer is yes.